# 2 phone lines 1 modem 1 router

Tags: modem, phone

My house next year will have the option of two separate phone lines, with two different numbers. I could theoretically set up two networks, with two modems and two routers.

Is there a way to configure a single modem/router to use both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two modems with a [Dual-WAN router](http://www.draytek.co.uk/products/vigor2920.html), although load-balancing would be rather pointless in a home, in my opinion.  Why pay for two broadband contracts?

Comment: There are plenty of great Dual WAN routers, including the SonicWall TZ-200 and TZ-210 (my personal favorites.) Your max speed on a single connection will still only be the max speed of one of your lines, but if you are doing something that connects to multiple sources (such as torrenting or other p2p activity), it will max out both connections.

Comment: It's for a house with 11 students in it, who all use the internet a lot. So theoretically there will be multiple sources, so a Dual-WAN router should work great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check eBay for old Netopia analog routers.  I had one of those back in the day.  It had 2 built-in modems and a serial port for a third external modem.